# Best Way to Monitor Types in DLL Files

Tags: c#

A portion of an application that I'm developing will monitor a particular folder for DLL files (.NET assemblies, to be more specific) that are placed within it, and it will look for any public types/classes that have the [Addin(...)] attribute.

These assemblies would be occasionally replaced with newer versions of themselves, so loading them into the current app domain doesn't seem like a good option.

Is the best way to approach this by setting up a separate app domain and loading in the assemblies, and then unload the app domain after the reflection/analysis is finished? Or is there a better way that might not require fully loading in the assemblies (thus not requiring the separate app domain) and might even be faster?

Comment: What are you actually asking here? Are you asking how to monitor a folder for changes or to scan an assembly for its declared types?

Comment: If you are looking for a plugin architecture, don't reinvent the wheel, use something like MEF or something that is already successfully built and trailed

Comment: I'm asking if my proposed approach is the best way to approach this (create a separate app domain, load the assemblies, get the types, then unload the app domain), or if there is a way that doesn't require the separate app domain.

Comment: TheGeneral - no I'm not setting up a plugin architecture. That is already done. I'm building a tool that will take inventory of addins that are built and updated by different team members.

Comment: And to be clear, I understand how to do each step, but just because something works doesn't mean it's the best way to do it. I'm always looking for better ways to approach problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while the overall approach was the same (temporary AppDomain), I was able to use the Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() call, which is presumably lighter than the full load.